# Accepted answer was "I don't know"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

My question relates to this one : [When does the revive timer resets?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70063/when-does-the-revive-timer-resets)

Somewhere, another user asked a close duplicate, not exact but close. He accepted the answer "I don't know", which doesn't seem to help anybody.

What should I do? Am I right to ask again?

Comment: Possibly flag this question as *not an answer*

Comment: You could offer a bounty and request a better answer.

Comment: @om-nom-nom After viewing it from another angle, it seems the answer is really an answer, I will try to add a link to the post so people don't need to, a)open his link to his question b)read comments looking for dup link, c)look for the answer

Comment: This really should be on meta.gaming, but... Uh, the migration failed to associate anyone's accounts. Simpler to leave it here for now until I figure out what went wrong there.

Comment: @Shog9 I tried to see your edit on the other site and the link to revisions didn't exist (I am not totally sure it was before the rejection though), and I say this info in case it help in something

Comment: Yeah, I just deleted it to reject the migration, @ajax. Would have been a pretty unfriendly migration with no one getting notified of anything. If you tried to follow the link at just the wrong time, you'd probably have been slapped back for that.

Comment: @Shog9 I did get a notification on my inbox, (a bluish-hard-to-spot, but still a notification)

Comment: @Shog9 I went to meta.stackexchange.com and it redirected here so I thought it would be appropriate to ask. Beside, this appeared to me as a generic question.

Comment: Well, I answered it fairly generically, but since you gave a specific example if you intend to apply what you've learned it would help to involve those in the community on which you hope to apply it. It's not a big deal - many Gaming users are fairly active here as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you're gonna ask again, explain why the answer on the existing question doesn't work for you. Since it was accepted, you've gotta assume it worked for the person asking...<sup>*</sup>

But yeah, the trick is to make it clear why the existing answer fails you. Re-asking just because you don't like an existing answer, or suspect there might be a better one, that's just wasting time - there might well *not* be. After all, if there was, someone might've posted it.

IMHO, that answer isn't just "I don't know" - he tries to describe his observations, they're just not very rigorous.

<sup>*or, I suppose, felt pressured into accepting it anyway</sup>

Answer (score 4):

> Am I right to ask again?

No, creating duplicates is not correct

If the question is unanswered or you are not satisfied with the answers, you can try to offer a bounty or edit the question to maximize the probability that the post get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to your question

1) Flag the answer as <s>"not an answer"</s> for diamond mod attention under "other"{*}.

2) You can edit the question to bump it. Try to improve it if you edit.

3) If the bump does not work, sacrifice some precious rep and give it a bounty.

<sup>*I don't think NAA is correct here--it *is* intended to answer the question. If not for the fact that it was accepted, NAA wouldnt've been applicable--you would downvote and comment instead,</sup>

### Answer to your situation

Looking at the comments, I went and saw the question (Initially I assumed the answer was literally "I don't know"). It sort of is valid, it provides some constructive material.

Whenever there is a question, not asked by you, which doesn't have *quite* the answers you want, bounty it and explain what you're looking for in the bounty reason box.

Comment: I agree that NAA isn't quite it, but what sort of mod flag do you have in mind?

Comment: @Anna the "other" one. It's nitpickyness, really, but I don't want to contradict something that I've posted elsewhere on meta. I'll clarify.

Comment: I disagree with this in this particular case. That answer may not be great, but it is an answer and may not even be wrong. Lacking any evidence to the contrary, asking a moderator to delete it *is* wrong.

Comment: Deleting and restoring just to remove the acceptance checkmark feels like an abuse of privileges.

Comment: @shog I know, see edit. At first I assumed that the answer was literally "I don't know"--I checked it out now.

Comment: @anna if the answer is literally "I don't know", IMO force-unaccepting it seems within boundaries. In this particular case it isn't..

Comment: @Tim: if an answer is bad enough to be worth removing the checkmark, it's probably also worth deleting. And... leaving deleted.

Comment: @shog hmm, right... Confused myself now.